# why is stringstream not reading additional data?

Tags: c++

I have this code and I am not able to understand the behavior of stringstream, I am new to C++.

**Please note that I have solved this problem, and I don't want a solution to work around this, I want to understand the behavior of the stream in this question.**

```cpp
void solve()
{

    string nl = "\n";

    string color;
    string line;
    string piece;


    cin >> color;
    cout << color << nl;

    cin.ignore(); // ignores the space

    getline(cin, line);

    stringstream ss(line);

    while(getline(ss, piece, ',')) {
        cout << piece << " " << piece.size() << nl;
    }

    cin >> color;
    cout << color << nl;

    cin.ignore(); // ignores the space

    getline(cin, line);

    ss << line;
    while(getline(ss, piece, ',')) {
        cout << piece << " " << piece.size() << nl;
    }

}
```

the input is this text

```
White: Ke1,Qd1
Black: Ke8,Qd8
```

the output is

```
White:
Ke1 3
Qd1 3
Black:
```

as we can see in the output, it doesn't print pieces after black color.

As per my understanding, `ss << line` is not working 2nd time. I am expecting that this line should append new characters in the line to `ss` stream ( as it is a writable stream), and I can read it later ( as it is a readable strear). Can you please help me understand if my expectation is wrong here?

As I mentioned I solved this problem by creating a new stringstream object when I needed it 2nd time so it worked perfectly, but I want to reuse the first object and understand the gap in my knowledge.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it's because the internal pointer for where it's reading from the stream is at the end, but the write pointer is at the beginning when you write the second line to it. You need to reset the stream first.

Comment: thank you very much for the insight. although I don't understand it completely as I am new to this, this definitely gives me direction to research more. thanks again for the reply.

Comment: The short version is that `cin.ignore` won't be enough to reach a point where the next `getline` call can read something, plus any failed read means that nothing can be read until the fail state is reset. I am pretty sure the proposed duplicate explains all of that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no if you remove ignore as well it doesn't work. issue is with the string stream object,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams have state. This state affects what they do.

Try adding this line after the `ss << line` line and see what it outputs.

```
cerr << "ss state: " << ss.good() << " " << ss.fail() << " "
     << ss.bad() << " " << ss.eof() << " " << ss.tellg() << " "
     << ss.tellp() << "\n:" << ss.str();
```

Do this first before reading on.

---

---

---

The first getline loop puts the stream in the eof (reached end of data) and fail (could not perform last operation) states. In this state, it does nothing. Inserting the new line has no effect. Trying to read anything has no effect. You have to reset the stream completely or (better) create a new one to actually do something useful with the stream.